# Autogenerating properties attributes when creating classes with xsd.exe

Tags: .net, xsd.exe

I'm using xsd.exe for a long time but right now I would like to go one step further and make it generate property and class attributes automatically from schema, or at least make it ignore attributes I put by myself into a code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `/classes` parameter

```
xsd.exe /classes foo.xsd
```

Which will generate `foo.cs` containing the corresponding .NET class.

Comment: I'm generating classes already as it's a main purpose why I keep using xsd.exe. I have a problem with attributes.

Comment: What particular problem are you having with them?

Comment: Particular problem I have is that they are missing :)

Comment: Could you post the *problematic* XSD file?

Comment: No. It is a project sensitive data.

Comment: Maybe I didnt put it clear - what i want to to is generate custom property attributes in a class I already generate based on XSD. So I want to change current process - XSD -> C# no attr to XSD -> C# with attr.

Comment: I wonder how do you expect this to happen without writing your own xsd.exe :-)

Comment: Indeed :) However I've started my own xsd.exe already, just looking for cutting corners